# Access class methods from instance of other class in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, oop

Let's say I have class A and class B. In class A I create an instance of class B. Class B has delegate methods that, when called, I want to call instance methods in class A. Is there a way to pass a reference to class A when instantiating class B?

Comment: If you are really talking about **class** methods (e.g. `+ (void)method;`) then you don't need a reference.  You need the reference if they are instance methods (e.g. `- (void)method;`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a delegate to return information to the first Class

Class B.h

```
@protocol delegateB <NSObject>
-(void)doSomething:(NSString *)data;
@end

@interface ClassB : UIViewController

@property(nonatomic, assign) id<delegateB> delegate; 

@end
```

Class B.m

```
@synthesize delegate = _delegate;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [_delegate doSomething:@"String to send"];
}
```

In the class A:

Class A.h

```
@interface ClassA : UIViewController

-(void)doSomething:(NSString *)data;

@end
```

Class A.m

When you instance the class, you need to assign self:

```
ClassB *cb = [[ClassB alloc] init];
cb.delegate = self;
```

To use the function:

```
-(void)doSomething:(NSString *)data{
    //do something whit the data
}
```

Comment: Why isn't `delegateA` actually named `delegateB`? It's a protocol defined by `ClassB` and there should be no indication of `ClassA` associated there.

Comment: And don't forget to add `@interface ClassA () <delegateB> ... @end` to `ClassA.m`.

Answer (score 0):

Add a property of type A to B and assign `self` to it after initialising. You could also pass `self` as an argument to the delegate method you mentioned. Actually this is common practice in cocoa (look at `UITableViewDelegate`)

Comment: Thank you - It was actually just a lack of understanding of delegates that was my problem!

Answer (score 0):

You can use type `Class` to pass a reference to a class. For class `A` use `[A class]` to get the referenece. But note that with a general class reference you won't be able to simply write `[aClassRef aClassMethod]`, because `Class` instancce can reference *any* class (so the compiler don't know if particular method is supported or not).

The actual solution should be closer to [what Julian suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34776794/3541063), but maybe this note will be useful in some way too.